# Why my switch don't work?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm making a chronometer(10 seconds) using `System.currentTimemillis`. And I have in a method that is refreshed 10 times per second the following code:

Start is the starting time of the activity, that it's "asked" in the onCreate method.
I know that `Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y))` works because when I do `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));` it returns me the time correctly.

So, my problem is that i don't know why the swich don't work properly.

```
long y=System.currentTimeMillis()-start;

switch (Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y))) {           
    case 1000:
        time.setText("3");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 2000:
        time.setText("2");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 3000:
        time.setText("1");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 4000:
        time.setText("GOOO!");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cuenta = 0;
        count.setText("0");
        break;

    case 5000:
        time.setText("1");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 6000:
        time.setText("2");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 7000:
        time.setText("3");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 8000:
        time.setText("4");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 9000:
        time.setText("5");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        break;

    case 10000:
        time.setText("Time!");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it won't exactly give these numbers 1000,2000,3000...

If the number give more or less then case will fail

**Edit:**

Try this

```
public static boolean isBetween(int x, int lower, int upper) {
  return lower <= x && x <= upper;
}

if (isBetween(num, 0, 1000)) {

  // do something

} else if (isBetween(num, 1001, 2000)) {

// do domething

}
...
```

...

Comment: And how can I make an interval of numbers inside a case?

Comment: Check intervals, not exact numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you check for a special time. I think you may want to use a code like this:

```
Integer val = Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y));
if(val<1000) {
    time.setText("3");
    time.setAnimation(anim);
} else if(val<2000) {
    time.setText("2");
    time.setAnimation(anim);
} else if(val<3000) {
    time.setText("1");
    time.setAnimation(anim);
} else if(val<4000) {
    time.setText("GOOO!");
    time.setAnimation(anim);
    count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cuenta = 0;
    count.setText("0");
} else /* and so on */
```

Basically you just check if your are in a special interval if not check the next one.

Comment: Hum, ok, maybe it will be better than the swich, Thanks

Comment: You might want to change the check from `if(val>1000)` to `if(val<1000)`

Comment: @SimonSays ahrg I mix them almost everytime up. Fixed!